# Snowflake stored procedure transaction behaviour not predictable

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been working with snowflake for some time now,but haven't actually worked with stored procedures involving transactions, i have a requirement of using streams and one such case is involving some business logic to be put into sp with conditional transactional rollback. i have written one such procedure but haven't had any success so far with rollback.

Here is the pseudo code of the thing i am trying to achieve:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SP(STREAM_NAME varchar,RECORD_ID_KEY varchar)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  AS
$$

var source_table_row1 = `SELECT RECORD_CONTENT::string from ${STREAM_NAME} limit 1;`;
var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:source_table_row1});
var raw_json='';

try
{
  var result_set1=statement1.execute();
  while (result_set1.next()) 
  {
    raw_json = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
  }
} catch(err)
{
  var result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
  result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
  return "detailed error  is:"+result; 
}

snowflake.execute({sqlText:"begin transaction"});
if(raw_json)
{
  try
  {
   
   //run DDL & DML statmetents  

    var result_set2=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:"DDL STMT"}).execute();
    var rs=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "DML STMT"}).execute();
    var rs2=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "FINAL DML STMT"}).execute();
 
  }catch(err){

    snowflake.execute ({sqlText: "rollback"});
    var errorMessage= "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
    errorMessage += "\n  Message: " + err.message+"    with net_status="+net_status;
    return errorMessage;
  }
}
else
{

  snowflake.execute({sqlText: "rollback"});
  return "no data present in source table";


}
snowflake.execute({sqlText:"rollback"});

return "successfully completed "
 
$$;
```

The problem here is that ,in case of everything goes fine ,i can see the sp performing the desired action,but for the cases where the query fails (eg. try to copy form table which doesn't exist). ,the code enters the catch block,and stored procedure completes,but i can't see any rollback activity happening as a result.
Could someone tell what am i missing here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is DDL code inside transaction:

```
snowflake.execute({sqlText:"begin transaction"});
...
//run DDL & DML statmetents  

var result_set2=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:"DDL STMT"}).execute();  -- here
var rs=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "DML STMT"}).execute();       
var rs2=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "FINAL DML STMT"}).execute();
...
snowflake.execute ({sqlText: "rollback"});
```

> [Transactions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html)
>
> **Explicit transactions should contain only DML statements and query statements. DDL statements implicitly commit active transactions (for details, see the DDL section).**
>
> **DDL**
>
> Each DDL statement executes as a separate transaction.
>
> If a DDL statement is executed while a transaction is active, the DDL statement:
>
> - Implicitly commits the active transaction.
> - Executes the DDL statement as a separate transaction.
>
> **Because a DDL statement is its own transaction, you cannot roll back a DDL statement; the transaction containing the DDL completes before you can execute an explicit ROLLBACK.**

Comment: Thanks ,@Lukasz Szozda, sorry for being late for adding a solution here, but you are spot on, i found this issue after having spent lot of hours scratching my head to see if i was doing something wrong in my procedure elsewhere

Comment: If I create a temporary table inside the stored procedure, will it implicitly commit the active transactions?